# How does Nuxt execute plugins?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to understand how Nuxt is composing its plugins when running in production mode.

For example, given the following plugin:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueClipboard from 'vue-clipboard2'

console.log(`plugins/clipboard.js`)

Vue.use(VueClipboard)
```

I will only see my `console.log` once at the time Nuxt service starts.

However, if I add an `export default` I can see the `console.log('plugins/clipboard.js: export default')` message every time I refresh my page:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueClipboard from 'vue-clipboard2'

console.log(`plugins/clipboard.js`)

Vue.use(VueClipboard)

export default () => {
  console.log(`plugins/clipboard.js: export default`)
}
```

So how is it that the `Vue.use(VueClipboard)` is executing on every page refresh when I never see the first `console.log` message?

Comment: Because the `clipboard` is bound to the Vue instance, it doesn't need the rest of your plugin data. When you export from it, then it's included in the transpiled JS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  So, if I'm understanding, the Vue instance is cached in memory.  Then on every page request Nuxt simply uses that Vue instance it created when it first started?

Comment: you can get rid of the exported function. ;)